# PHP sql does not return all values

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I do this query directly from PHP my admin I got 5 results.

```
SELECT img FROM `table`.`goog` WHERE `url` LIKE '%google.com%' and `pictureID` != 'picture_50d22657a423b6.62354164';
```

however, when my code

```
$sql2 = "SELECT img FROM `table`.`goog` WHERE `url` LIKE '%$url%' and `pictureID` != '$pictureID';";
    // echo $sql2;
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
$rows2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2);

mysql_close($con);

print_r(count($rows2));

echo "<br/>";

echo $sql2;
```

it prints out

```
2 
SELECT img FROM `ashkan`.`goog` WHERE `url` LIKE '%66.228.42.45%' and `pictureID` != 'picture_50d22657a423b6.62354164';
```

I would also like to note that the query I run inside of php my admin is copied from what my code returns..

So, why does one returns only 2 items, and the other returns 5?

**EDIT**

I added the following to the bottom

```
var_dump($rows2);
echo "<br/>";
echo mysql_num_rows($result2);
```

and got this

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "b" ["img"]=> string(1) "b" } 
5
```

I have something that manually selects a row

Essentially I want to be able to do

```
echo $rows2[somenum]; //that some number is at random and only one at a time
```

however, as is, I can only access item 0 and not all five.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Please see my post with updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UPDATED CODE

Here's your updated code:

```
$mysqlQuery=mysql_query("SELECT img FROM `table`.`goog` WHERE `url` LIKE '%$url%' and `pictureID` != '$pictureID");
$databaseArray=array();

while($arrayQuery=mysql_fetch_array($mysqlQuery))
{
    $imageName=$arrayQuery['img'];
    
    $databaseArray[]=$imageName;
}

echo "Database returned ".count($databaseArray)." rows.";

print_r($databaseArray);

echo $databaseArray[0]; // prints image name row 1
echo $databaseArray[1]; // prints image name row 2
echo $databaseArray[2]; // prints image name row 3
// etc etc etc
```

---

### Old code

Do this:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT img FROM `table`.`goog` WHERE `url` LIKE '%$url%' and `pictureID` != '$pictureID';";
    // echo $sql2;
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
    var_dump($data);
}
```

[mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) only returns one row at a time. The code above loops all the rows find in your database. If you only want to count the rows, then check [mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)() function.

You should also use mysqli_* and not mysql_*, because it's deprecated. Please read more at:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: i added some updates above. How can I achieve what I added after I edited it.

Comment: You don't have to. It's automatically closed at the end of the page load. Else you could always close it at the bottom of the page, if you want. But it's not needed as I said. Also, don't forget to set the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_fetch_array()` only fetches one row from result set and moves the pointer ahead one.

If you want a count of the number of rows a query returns use [`mysql_num_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

```
echo mysql_num_rows($result2);
```

Answer (score 1):

By using:

`print_r(count($rows2));`

Your just counting the number of array keys for this row

You should be doing this instead:

`echo mysql_num_rows($result2);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over the results.

```
$sql2 = "SELECT img FROM `table`.`goog` WHERE `url` LIKE '%$url%' and `pictureID` != '$pictureID';";
    // echo $sql2;
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);

// iterate over the results
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    print_r($row); 
}

mysql_close($con);
```